# Input Control type Text Reference In Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have the following code

```
  <input runat="server" id="Name" type="text" name="Name"/>


    cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@NAME", Name.value);
```

I am trying to capture the data I enter inside my control and (Name.value) always equals ""
No matter what I type. I know they are mapped correctly as if I switch it to a textbox it works fine I would like to get this input working as well.

EDITED 
This seems to work not sure if this is the proper way to do this but any reason why this would work but Name.value does not?

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", Request.Form["Name]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use html elements in a code behind you have to add the `runat=server` attribute.

```
<input runat="server" id="Name" type="text" name="Name" ClientIdMode="static"/>
```

Setting the `ClientIdMode` to `static` should allow you to use the same id in the code behind as in the html, just be careful not to create conflicts.

Name will be cast as an `HtmlInputControl`, and when the page posts back, `Name.Value` will have the value of the input with the text that was entered.  So then you can do:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("parameterename", Name.Value);
```

Comment: I tried this out and I am able to access the control in codebehind but when I try to capture the input it is null.When the debugger hits that line even though I have a value in the name control it shows "" as the value. Any Ideas?

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", Request.Form["Name]); This way seems to be working why would this work and the way you suggested not?

Comment: One reason could be where in the page life cycle you access the value.  The value for form elements isn't set until the `Load` event.  So if you're looking at before, then that would cause the problem.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Another reason is that you might have forgotten `runat="server"` on your form element: `<form runat="server">`

Comment: I do have the runat="server" and not sure how it could be the page life cycle. If I replace the control with <asp:Textbox and grab .Text instead of value it works. THanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

`runat="server"` is what makes things available to code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

html control should inside the form tag and also you need to add `runat="server"` attribute. then you can access it by id.

```
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("parameterename", Name.Value);
```

note that if the input id is `Name` you can't get Text as `"name.text"` you need to get the `Value` of it